# Mono 3.0.6 on Raspberry PI - is it supported?

Tags: mono, debian, raspberry-pi

I am following instructions from this [page](http://mono-project.com/DistroPackages/Debian) to install Mono 3.0.6 on my Raspberry PI. Unfortunately without success:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mono-complete : Depends: mono-devel (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-mcs (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-gmcs (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-dmcs (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-csharp-shell (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-2.0-gac (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-2.0-service (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: mono-4.0-service (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: monodoc-base (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: monodoc-manual (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
                 Depends: libmono-cil-dev (= 2.10.8.1-5) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Anyone know if what I am trying to do is supported? Any hints or workarounds? 
Note: I specifically want to try version 3.0.6. I was able to install the stable version but there is a bug that is blocking me and I am hoping it's fixed in 3.0.6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently at the moment Mono is not really supported on armhf and this is what the regular Raspbian "wheezy" distro is. I tried Soft-float Debian “wheezy” and the original issue I had was gone even on 2.10.8. When I tried upgrading to a newer version `apt-get` just said "mono-complete is already the newest version". [Here](http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/05/19/raspberry-pi-mono-ef6-defeat/) is the long version of the story.

Answer (score 2):

It seems armhf is now supported in mono:
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?t=62496&p=468500

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK mono 3.0.6 was just included in debian/experimental, so I guess you're not using this version.

Comment: I did add `deb http://debian.meebey.net/experimental/mono /` to the /etc/apt/sources. Without this line version 2.8.x is being (successfully) installed. So, I believe it is trying to install 3.0.6 but fails for some reason.

Comment: uninstall all mono packages before adding that to apt sources?

Comment: did you uninstall all of them, and then tried installing the new ones again?

Comment: Yes I did completely uninstall mono 2.8, updated sources and tried installing 3.0.x but it resulted in errors above.

Comment: Please don't leave us hanging!

Comment: @EricFalsken - take a look at my post for which I needed this - http://blog.3d-logic.com/2013/05/19/raspberry-pi-mono-ef6-defeat/. Apparently Mono armhf is currently not really supported. I ended up using soft wheezy (armel) but for this version mono won't even try installing anything later than 2.10.8 :(

Comment: And now the answer to life, the universe, and everything.... how is this not the accepted answer... though I guess it still doesn't get Mono3 running on a pi...

Comment: I will post an answer to this question soon.